# how to observe a Object's state in java

Tags: java, state, database

I'm designing a ConnectionPool in java SE.
now, i meet a question.

The pool will hold 20 Reference of the bridge between client Program and DBMS which we call it
Connection.

and my question is like that
when the client Program is busy, i hold all 20 References,
but when it is free, I want the program free 5 Connection,
if there are several Connection free still in long time, free another 5 Connection, 
how ever, when program turn to busy, build 5 new Connection, again and again.

anyone have a way to do it, thank you for read my question

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you doing when a connection is "free"?  Do you have a free list?  If so, just close the connection when the free list reaches 5.

Comment: In fact, I'm wirting a program which will run on a DB server.

Comment: In fact, I'm code a program which will run on a DB server.I define a ArrayBlockingList to save the Connection References."free" means if there is only 15 Connections is needed when the server is busiest,than 5 Connections will still won't be useful,these Connections should be destoried.how ever, after a period time run,server true free a little, close more Connection,such like this.in summary,the number of Connection should map to how busy the Server is.busy,build several, free destory several. Thank you for you help

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this?  Your server needs to be capable of handling the maximum number of connections you need. This is the critical number. The number you use when it is not busy doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Why not start with just 1 or 2  connections and add another ones when needed? You can of course define the MAX that should not be exceeded.

Comment: all for performance.Because there is thousands  client will send request to the Server concurrently,and build Connection between program and DB will take 100-1500ms,at the same time it cost a lot of resource.so,before the request come,the connection should have built.and when finish the request,the connection should be put back to pool instand of destory it,then another request could use it without to build a new connection

Comment: reply Peter:for performance,too.The performance curve is regular.in daytime,many clients send request,the server should respond in time,server can focus on client's request.At night, the request will be less, server should save the resource to do other thing.just like refresh,back-up or optimize allocation of resources